# Reading space separated numbers from stdin into a linked list

Tags: c, scanf, stdin

I am trying to read numbers separated by spaces from stdin into a c program and on every number I am adding a node to linked list.

Input from stdin:

```
20
20 30 123 34 50
```

The first line from stdin (20) is for looking up an item with number 20.
The second line contains data items to inserted into a linked list
Upon entering it should end the loop but it's not and I am not sure what I am missing out here.

```
  char follow;
  scanf("%d", &M);
  while(((count = scanf("%d%c", &element, &follow)) > 0))
    {
      if(count == 2 && isspace(follow) || count == 1)
        {
          printf("count = %d and element = %d\n", count, element);
          push(&root, element);
        }
      else{
        break;
      }
    }
```

The problem is that the while loop doesn't end on hitting enter.

Comment: You don't need to read whitespace if using the `"%d"` format, it will skip leading whitespace.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I tried doing this but no luck  while(((count = scanf("%d", &element)) > 0))
    {
      printf("count = %d and element = %d\n", count, element);
      push(&root, element);
    }

Comment: Now the question is, will there be *other* input after the one you show? Any input at all? Then you might have to read the line as a line using e.g. `fgets`, split the input on space (with e.g. `strtok`) and explicitly convert the numbers to integers (with e.g. `strtol`). If that's the only input the user will ever give the program, then you don't need the white-space handling at all, but you need the user to press the "eof" key (`CTRL-Z` on Windows, `CTRL-D` on POSIX systems like Linux or OSX) to terminate the input. Or use the line-handling as described above here too.

Comment: That's because a newline character is a `white space` character. Thus `isspace('\n')` will return true.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it seems that enter key is the sentinel.

Comment: Why not `while (((count = scanf (" %d", &element)) == 1))` as the only loop control? Unless I'm missing something, after you read `M`, all you care about is reading the remaining numbers into `push (&root, element);`, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - somehow this doesn't work. I tried this and the loop was not getting over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would change your if conditional as in:

```
if ((count == 2 && isspace(follow) && follow != '\n') || count == 1)
```

Because both space `' '` and newline `'\n'` are empty space, `isspace` itself is not enough.